# Why is this splice removing the wrong item in my ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, indexof, array-splice

I'm trying to splice out items in this ng-repeat based on their $index.  It works for adding them just fine, but when I try to delete that item using that same code it removes only the last item of the array as if it were doing the pop() method.  I have no idea why.  Here is my object I'm repeating:

```
"lineItems": [
  {
    "area": "Bedroom",
    "label": "Sleep Time",
    "notes": "",
    "pictures": [],
    "subLineItems": [
      {
        "label": "Flooring",
        "data": {
          "rates": [
            {
              "label": "Damaged",
              "value": "1",
              "color": "damaged-red"
            },
            {
              "label": "Poor",
              "value": "2",
              "color": "poor-orange"
            },
            {
              "label": "Dirty",
              "value": "3",
              "color": "dirty-yellow"
            },
            {
              "label": "Fair",
              "value": "4",
              "color": "fair-light-blue"
            },
            {
              "label": "Good",
              "value": "5",
              "color": "good-green"
            }
          ]
        },
        "items": [
          [
            {
              "uuid": "6f5fed0c-db03-41a0-a575-15af3ad3",
              "label": "Hot Water Tank",
              "selected": false,
              "price": 500,
              "labor": [
                {
                  "uuid": "8b9f9ea2-b163-45c0-9a80-087a8e16",
                  "label": "Install Carpet Basic",
                  "selected": false,
                  "price": "1.00"
                },
                {
                  "uuid": "a696faca-197a-4fd9-972c-05f197f4",
                  "label": "Install Trim Basic",
                  "selected": false,
                  "price": "0.50"
                },
                {
                  "uuid": null,
                  "label": "Select",
                  "selected": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "uuid": "7815a160-7b70-48d1-ba32-8c232654",
              "label": "Ceiling Fan Replacement",
              "selected": false,
              "price": 175,
              "labor": [
                {
                  "uuid": "8b9f9ea2-b163-45c0-9a80-087a8e16",
                  "label": "Install Carpet Basic",
                  "selected": false,
                  "price": "1.00"
                },
                {
                  "uuid": "a696faca-197a-4fd9-972c-05f197f4",
                  "label": "Install Trim Basic",
                  "selected": false,
                  "price": "0.50"
                },
                {
                  "uuid": null,
                  "label": "Select",
                  "selected": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "uuid": null,
              "label": "Select",
              "selected": true
            }
          ]
        ],
        "rate": null,
        "notes": null,
        "pictures": []
      }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
                            <ul class="list-inline col-xs-12">
                                   <form class="form-inline col-xs-12" id="expenseForm">
                                   <!-- li = items[0].array -->
                                      <li ng-repeat="item in subLineItem.items track by $index" class="bouncy-slide-left" ng-class-even="'even-stripe'">
                                         <!-- MATERIALS -->
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-3" style="margin-left: 0px !important">
                                            <label for="material">{{labels.material.label}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <select name="material" class="form-control" ng-model="expense.mat.item" style="width: 125px">
                                               <option value="{{mat.uuid}}" ng-repeat="mat in item" ng-selected="mat.selected">{{mat.label}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                                            <label>{{labels.material_qty.label}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text"  ng-model="item.mat.qty" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="{{labels.material_qty.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px; overflow: scroll">
                                         </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                                            <label>{{labels.material_cost.label}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="expense.mat.price" class="form-control" name="labor"  placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px; overflow: scroll">
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                                            <label>{{labels.totals.total}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="expense.mat.total" class="form-control" name="labor" placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px; overflow: scroll">
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="icon-str col-xs-1" style="padding-left: 0px" ng-click="removeItem($parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$index, $index)">
                                                <label for=""></label>
                                                <br>
                                                <i class="fa-trash delete-inspec"></i>
                                            </div> 
                                        <!-- LABOR  ITEMS -->
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                                            <label for="labor">{{labels.labor.label}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <select name="labor" class="form-control" ng-model="item.lab.item" style="width: 125px">
                                               <option value="{{lab.uuid}}" ng-repeat="lab in item[0].labor" ng-selected="lab.selected">{{lab.label}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                                            <label>{{labels.material_qty.label}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.lab.qty" class="form-control" name="hours" placeholder="{{labels.labor_qty.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px;overflow: scroll">
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                                            <label>{{labels.labor_cost.label}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.lab.price" class="form-control" name="labor" placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px;overflow: scroll">
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-group col-xs-2 ">
                                            <label>{{labels.totals.total}}</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.lab.total" class="form-control" name="labor" placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px;overflow: scroll">
                                         </div>
                                         <!-- RESPONSIBLE PARTY -->
                                         <div class="form-group row col-xs-12" style="margin-left:0px !important; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid #888">
                                           <div class="col-xs-5 text-left" style="padding-right: 0px">
                                                <label for="expenses">{{labels.responsible.label}}</label>
                                                <br>
                                                <select name="expenses" ng-model="expense.responsible" class="form-control" style="width: 200px">
                                                   <option value="{{resp.value}}" ng-repeat="resp in labels.responsibleParty" ng-selected="resp.selected">{{resp.label}}</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                      </li>
                                   </form>
                                </ul>
```

Here is my controller :

```
   //add line item when NEW button is pressed
   $scope.add = function(a, b){
       //create the source of the copy, and where you want to send it (destination is a blank array)
       var mySource = $scope.lineItems[0].subLineItems[0].items[0];
       var myDestination = [];
       //copy the source and send it to destination
       angular.extend( myDestination, mySource);
       //push that newly built array into the array
       $scope.lineItems[a].subLineItems[b].items.push(myDestination);
       //show the updated version of that array
       console.log( $scope.lineItems[a].subLineItems[b].items);
   };
   //remove item from array
   $scope.removeItem = function(a, b, c){
       console.log(a, b, c);
       $scope.lineItems[a].subLineItems[b].items.splice(c, 1);
       console.warn($scope.lineItems[a].subLineItems[b].items);
   };
```

This prints the correct number in a console, but actually removes the last item in the items array.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your parent tags.

`removeItem($parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$index, $index)`

Here, the `$parent` is according to divisions in your html and not according to the array.
Try some other logic to target the subarrays.

Comment: Thanks Hardeep, could you please expand on that a little more?  Maybe give a suggestion some other logic I could use?

Comment: All your array problems need to be solved by your controller and not your HTML template. Suppose, in the future you change your html file, then accordingly you will be needing to tweek $parent.$parent.. and so on.

Get the index of subarray from html directly by $index, and then target that subarray from your controller like $scope.lineItems['subLineItems']['rates'][ $index ].

Comment: Make it live at plunkr or jsfiddle, I can help you out.